# Grunt registration task dont work

Tags: gruntjs

I use only jshint and I configured it like as in the oficial documentation. It probably has no commas missing too. Here is the code:

```
module.export = function(grunt){
grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    jshint: {
        files: {
            src: ['Gruntfile.js', 'app.js'] 
        },

        options: {
            reporter: require('jshint-stylish'),
            globals: {
                console: true,
                module: true,
            },
        },

        watch: {
          files: ['<%= jshint.files %>'],
          tasks: ['jshint'],
        }
    }
});
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
grunt.registerTask('default', ["jshint"]);

};
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Warning: Task "jshint" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings. and  grunt
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...you have a typo on the very first line.

Change the first line to:

```
module.exports = function(grunt){
```

Note the 's' on `exports`.